# Aggregate object in DDD

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, domain-driven-design

I have made an aggregate class named `Question`. This contains references to `Answer`, `Category`, `Feedback` objects. Should the QuestionRepository be the class that contains all methods quering the database that relates to the Question but also all the methods for quering the Feedback, Answer etc? Or should these be seperate classes such as QuestionRepository, FeedbackRepository and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [DDD web site](http://domaindrivendesign.org/node/123) :

> For each type of object that needs global access, create an object
>   that can provide the illusion of an in-memory collection of all
>   objects of that type.

A repository is used when you need direct access to an entity, i.e. when there's no other convenient way to get hold of that entity than fetching it from a persistent store directly. In contrast, if you consider that the entity is most of the time easily obtainable through traversal of another object you've already got at hand, then there's no need for a repository. It seems to be the case with Answer, Category, and Feedback here.

Usually repositories are only for aggregate roots, though there may be exceptions.

I suggest you read the DDD blue book or some tutorial to get a basic comprehension of the DDD building blocks before you start building your domain model.

Comment: But I want to fetch all Feedback and then go from Feedback to the Question it is attached. Should the Question repository fetch Feedback entities then?

Comment: I'd avoid having the Question repository return Feedbacks. If Feedback really is one of the main entry points in your application (ie there's a screen displaying only feedbacks without their questions, the user can search Feedbacks with detailed criteria...), I'd give it its own Repository and perhaps even make it an Aggregate Root. I guess it boils down to "will it ever make sense to have a Feedback without its Question ?"

Comment: A Feedback is always associated with a Question. However, I want to list all Feedbacks in the system on its own view (among other things),  and when the user clicks a Feedback row it will display the associated Question.

Comment: Here's how I'd handle it. In the Domain layer, load an object graph containing all relevant Questions (via QuestionRepository.LoadAll() or QuestionRepository.LoadByWhatever()). In the Presentation layer, use another object graph that corresponds to the first one seen from another angle : a collection of Feedbacks with a reference to its Question for each Feedback. You can do this through DTO mapping.

Answer (score 2):

From the way you have explained , I am assuming that each Question will have 1 or more Answers , 1 or more Feedback and the Question belongs to a particular Category

Since the Answer and Feedback are dependent on Question and cannot exist independently , you can have a single QuestionRepository for these 3 entities .

Coming to Category , category is more of a static entity which IMO is a static list , so all such static entities can be grouped together in a StaticRepository

Comment: You are right about the Question relationship. But I have a view that lists all the e.g. Feedbacks, then when you click a Feedback row you will see the feedback as well as the question it belongs to. Should I then query the QuestionRepository then?

Comment: Yes and it should return a simplistic model suitable for the view model.

Comment: Ok, so even though it is not Questions I return from the method (it is Feedback) the method for doing so should be in the QuestionRepository because the Feedback doesn't live on its own? It is still attached to a Question even though you go trough the relationship property.